# Convert string to a variable name in R - does not work in a function

Tags: r

I have a problem that converting string to a variable name in R, does not always work in a function. I have tried everything, ad I still do not understand the problem. Hopefully, reproducible example follows:

```
library(emmeans)
library(dplyr)


a <- 1:10 + rnorm(10,0,1)
b <- c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5))
c <- a

df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df$c[df$b=="b"] <- (-0.5*df$a[df$b=="b"])
df$c <- df$c + rnorm(10.0,1)



func.1 <- function(formula, df){
  mf <- as.list(match.call())
  lm.res <- lm(mf$formula, data=df)
  nm.1 <- names(lm.res$model)[1]
  nm.2 <- names(lm.res$model)[2]
  nm.3 <- names(lm.res$model)[3]
  print(summary(lm.res)$coefficients)
  cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  print(anova(lm.res))
  cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  m.slope <- emtrends(lm.res, nm.2, var=nm.3)
  print(m.slope)
  cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  print(pairs(m.slope))
  cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  #m.inter <- emmeans(lm.res, nm.2, at = list(eval(parse(text = nm.3))=88))
  # print(m.inter)
  # print(pairs(m.inter))
  cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  df %>%
    group_by(eval(parse(text = nm.2))) %>%
    summarise(r = sqrt(summary(lm(eval(parse(text = nm.1)) ~ eval(parse(text = nm.3))))$r.squared))
}
```

to execute:

```
func.1(c ~ b:a, df)
```

Everything works fine until I uncomment three commented lines. Then I got the following error

```
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = eval(parse(text = nm.2))`.
x object 'nm.2' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

The culprit is the following line:

```
m.inter <- emmeans(lm.res, nm.2, at = list(eval(parse(text = nm.3))=88))
```

Thank you.

Miloš

Comment: Hi, what is the " = 88" in the culprit line? It seems to give a syntax error, and puts out a result if simply removed

Comment: Thank you. Covariate takes value 88. If that value is omitted covariate takes the average value. I would like to estimate and compare group values at certain covariate values.

Comment: Hmm, I unfortunately no not know how to handle that, sorry.

Comment: Seems to me you need to add the environment where nm.3 exists to the eval() call.

Comment: Or maybe try: `atlist = list(88); names(atlist) = nm.3; emmeans(lm.res, nm.2, at = atlist)`